# SQL Calculate cumulative value over a period

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative revenue over time since 2020-01-01. I have user level revenue data with the following schema

```
create table revenue
(
  game_id        varchar(255),
  user_id        varchar(255),
  amount         int,
  activity_date  varchar(255)
);

insert into revenue
  (game_id, user_id, amount, activity_date)
values
  ('Racing', 'ABC123', 5, '2020-01-01'),
  ('Racing', 'ABC123', 1, '2020-01-04'),
  ('Racing', 'CDE123', 1, '2020-01-04'),
  ('DH', 'CDE123', 100, '2020-01-03'),
  ('DH', 'CDE456', 10, '2020-01-02'),
  ('DH', 'CDE789', 5, '2020-01-02'),
  ('DH', 'CDE456', 1, '2020-01-03'),
  ('DH', 'CDE456', 1, '2020-01-03');
```

Expected Output

```
Game    Age    Cum_rev    Total_unique_payers_per_game
Racing  0      5          2
Racing  1      5          2
Racing  2      5          2
Racing  3      7          2
DH      0      0          3
DH      1      15         3
DH      2      117        3
DH      3      117        3
```

Age is calculated as the difference between transaction date and 2020-01-01.
I'm using the below logic

```
SELECT game_id, DATEDIFF(activity_date ,'2020-01-01') as Age,count(user_id) as Total_unique_payers
from REVENUE
```

[SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rrgti23gNRA5U3uaRRtXPq/1)
How do I calculate the cumulative revenue?

Comment: `Cum_rev` is a result from `SUM(amount)`? Also, an aggregation without `GROUP BY` is not compatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: You can do by `sum(amount) / count(user_id)`

Comment: Yes cumulative revenue is calculated over time. it is `SUM(amount)`. We should use group by if we are aggregating

Comment: @zealous - what about the date? The Age is 0,1,2,3

Comment: Age should count like this `DATEDIFF(activity_date,'2020-01-01')` .. using comma instead.

Comment: @tcadidot0 correct, but how do we calculate the cumulative amount over activity date

Comment: I could not understand your logic on the expected output. Can you explain why you have 4 'racing' lines and 1 'DH'?

Comment: What is your complete query - including `GROUP BY`? Here's [a fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rrgti23gNRA5U3uaRRtXPq/1). You can edit the query and test run in the fiddle and click update. Once it generates new link, just copy and paste it into your question. Thanks

Comment: @JorgeCampos -  for game_id Racing we start with an amount of 5 on 2020-01-01 so Age is 0. on 2020-01-02 the amount is still 5 because we don't have a transaction on that day. on 2020-01-03 the amount is 5. but on 2020-01-04 the amount is 7 because we have 2 transactions on this day

Comment: That above suggestion from @tcadidot0 will help a lot. Are you trying to generate a line per day based on the max date per game? (which would correspond with the age column)

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes you got that right

Comment: What about gaps? do you care about gaps? I'm trying to understand whether you will need a days table or not with this question

Comment: @JorgeCampos - yes we would need a row for each day between the gaps.

Comment: is the number of players also cumulative?

Comment: @JorgeCampos no. In Racing there are a total of 2 players(user_ids) and DH has 3 players

Comment: So you want then the total number of players without considering the `age`... I was under the impression that the numbers of players should match the age... thats even easier

Comment: @JorgeCampos - Total_payer_count and age are independent

Comment: @JorgeCampos Just curious, are you using Window functions? I'm trying that in the https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rrgti23gNRA5U3uaRRtXPq/3

Comment: No, I'm using techniques available in MySQL 5.7 to get above results...

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MySQL 5.7 the only way of doing it is using its variables system, its trick though it works. It simulates the the Windowing Functions used by @Used_By_Already on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61151902/460557)

Since you mentioned that you care about the gaps, you need first to create a dates table, that's easily done as:

```
create table dates_view (
  date_day date
);

insert into dates_view
select date_add( '2019-12-31', INTERVAL @rownum:=@rownum+1 day ) as date_day
from (
   select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
   union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
   union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) a, (
   select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
   union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
   union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) b, (select @rownum:=0) r;

-- Note: each set of select union above will multiply the number 
-- of days by 10, so if you need more days in your table just add more
-- set as above "a" or "b" sets
```

After having your Dates table you have to cross join it with your current `revenue` table the catch is you want the number of players to be independent of the cumulative `amount` so you need to compute it independently in a subquery.

You also need to compute the `max(activity_date)` of your `revenue` table in order to limit the results until to it.

So below query will do just it (based on your current sample data):

```
set @_sum:=0;       -- Note: this two lines depends on the client
set @_currGame:=''; -- you are using. Some accumulate variable per session
                    -- some doesn't, below site, for instance does

select a.game_id,
       a.age,
       case when @_currGame = game_id 
            then @_sum:=coalesce(samount,0) + @_sum
            else @_sum:=coalesce(samount,0) end as Cum_rev,
       a.Total_unique_payers_per_game,
       @_currGame := game_id varComputeCurrGame
from 
    (
    select players.game_id, 
           rev.samount,
           datediff(dv.date_day, '2020-01-01') age,
           players.noPlayers Total_unique_payers_per_game
       from (select @_sum:=0) am,
            dates_view dv
             cross join (select max(activity_date) maxDate from revenue) md 
               on dv.date_day <= md.maxDate
             cross join (select game_id, count(distinct user_id) noPlayers 
                           from revenue group by game_id) players
             left join (select game_id, activity_date, sum(amount) samount 
                          from revenue group by game_id, activity_date) rev
                on players.game_id = rev.game_id
                   and dv.date_day = rev.activity_date
    ) a,
    (select @_sum:=0) s,
    (select @_currGame='') x
order by a.game_id desc, a.age;
```

This will result in:

```
  game_id   age  Cum_rev  Total_unique_payers_per_game   varComputeCurrGame
   Racing    0      5             2                            Racing
   Racing    1      5             2                            Racing
   Racing    2      5             2                            Racing
   Racing    3      7             2                            Racing
   DH        0      0             3                            DH    
   DH        1      15            3                            DH    
   DH        2      117           3                            DH    
   DH        3      117           3                            DH
```

See it working here (you need to run it): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qifZ6hmpvcSZYwhLDv613d/2

Here is a version for MySQL 8.x that supports windowing functions:

```
select distinct agetable.game_id,
       agetable.age,
       sum(coalesce(r1.amount,0)) 
             over (partition by agetable.game_id 
                     order by agetable.game_id, agetable.age) as sm,
       agetable.ttplayers
from
    (
    select r.game_id, dv.date_day, datediff(dv.date_day, '2020-01-01') age, p.ttplayers
    from dates_view dv
          cross join (select distinct game_id, activity_date from revenue) r 
            on dv.date_day <= (select max(activity_date) from revenue)
          left join (select game_id, count(distinct user_id) ttplayers from revenue group by game_id) p
            on r.game_id = p.game_id
    group by r.game_id desc, dv.date_day, age, p.ttplayers
    ) agetable
    left join revenue r1
      on agetable.date_day = r1.activity_date
         and r1.game_id = agetable.game_id
order by agetable.game_id desc, agetable.age
```

Answer (score 1):

For the following you need a version of MySQL that supports the `over()` clause (MySQL 8+)  - I used MariaDB 10.4 below (MySQL 8 wasn't working at the site when I tried)

> ```
> create table revenue
> (
>   game_id        varchar(255),
>   user_id        varchar(255),
>   amount         int,
>   activity_date  varchar(255)
> );
>
> insert into revenue
>   (game_id, user_id, amount, activity_date)
> values
>   ('Racing', 'ABC123', 5, '2020-01-01'),
>   ('Racing', 'ABC123', 1, '2020-01-04'),
>   ('Racing', 'CDE123', 1, '2020-01-04'),
>   ('DH', 'CDE123', 100, '2020-01-03'),
>   ('DH', 'CDE456', 10, '2020-01-02'),
>   ('DH', 'CDE789', 5, '2020-01-02'),
>   ('DH', 'CDE456', 1, '2020-01-03'),
>   ('DH', 'CDE456', 1, '2020-01-03');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   game_id
> , user_id
> , activity_date
> , amount
> , sum(amount) over(order by activity_date, user_id) as running_sum
> , (select count(distinct user_id) from revenue) as Total_unique_payers
> from revenue
> order by
>   activity_date
> , user_id
> ```
>
> ```
> game_id | user_id | activity_date | amount | running_sum | Total_unique_payers
> :------ | :------ | :------------ | -----: | ----------: | ------------------:
> Racing  | ABC123  | 2020-01-01    |      5 |           5 |                   4
> DH      | CDE456  | 2020-01-02    |     10 |          15 |                   4
> DH      | CDE789  | 2020-01-02    |      5 |          20 |                   4
> DH      | CDE123  | 2020-01-03    |    100 |         120 |                   4
> DH      | CDE456  | 2020-01-03    |      1 |         122 |                   4
> DH      | CDE456  | 2020-01-03    |      1 |         122 |                   4
> Racing  | ABC123  | 2020-01-04    |      1 |         123 |                   4
> Racing  | CDE123  | 2020-01-04    |      1 |         124 |                   4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ec17d86fe1f0b723aa0b19ed8b77f75e)*

Changing the order of calculation inside the over clause affects how the running sum is calculated: e.g.

> ```
> SELECT
>   game_id
> , user_id
> , activity_date
> , amount
> , sum(amount) over(order by game_id DESC, activity_date, user_id) as running_sum
> , (select count(distinct user_id) from revenue) as Total_unique_payers
> from revenue
> order by
>   game_id DESC
> , activity_date
> , user_id
> ```
>
> ```
> game_id | user_id | activity_date | amount | running_sum | Total_unique_payers
> :------ | :------ | :------------ | -----: | ----------: | ------------------:
> Racing  | ABC123  | 2020-01-01    |      5 |           5 |                   4
> Racing  | ABC123  | 2020-01-04    |      1 |           6 |                   4
> Racing  | CDE123  | 2020-01-04    |      1 |           7 |                   4
> DH      | CDE456  | 2020-01-02    |     10 |          17 |                   4
> DH      | CDE789  | 2020-01-02    |      5 |          22 |                   4
> DH      | CDE123  | 2020-01-03    |    100 |         122 |                   4
> DH      | CDE456  | 2020-01-03    |      1 |         124 |                   4
> DH      | CDE456  | 2020-01-03    |      1 |         124 |                   4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1d3d32add71ab24f02b2b1a2fac1583f)*

Comment: It can be done in versions prior to 8 without windowing functions.

Comment: I did not say it couldn't... just that I chose to do so

Comment: You mentioned that a version that supports `over` is needed. Therefore my comment, It would be more accurate It can be done with a version that supports `over` :)

Comment: @Used_By_Already - This is good idea to use `over` clause. I added a few more rows to the expected output to get more clarity. But the running sum is calculating for all game_id in your query. The cumulative revenue should be calculated as follows eg for game_id Racing we start with an amount of 5 on 2020-01-01 so Age is 0. on 2020-01-02 the amount is still 5 because we don't have a transaction on that day. on 2020-01-03 the amount is 5. but on 2020-01-04 the amount is 7 because we have 2 transactions on this day

Comment: @JorgeCampos "For the following..." (i.e. my suggested solution) you do need a version that support `over()` but if you choose to follow some other solution then perhaps you do not. i.e. For my suggested solution there is a version requirement. I really feel I had been sufficiently specific.

Comment: Hmmm, you are right... sorry my missundertanding :)